# How do I hide read comments from my SE inbox?

Tags: support

I want to hide 144 pages of comments in my account but nowhere can I find a 'delete' instruction. This may be the wrong site to ask, but please - someone - tell me how to get rid of this unwanted collection of comments!

Comment: Hi Anne, I think only a Moderator or CM could do this kind of action in bulk - one page at a time. When used correctly, Comments should be useful additions and information for understanding the Question or Answer they're attached to, so deleting every single comment you've ever posted would be a lot of content deletion, and may cause others' content to make less sense. On all SE sites we usually try to avoid large scale destruction of content. Is there a particular reason you're seeking to do this? I'll try and write a more complete answer when I get a chance to.

Comment: @Steve can help No, I don't want to delete my comments that appear in answers. I just want to erase the massive 144 page list in my personal account. I don't need it. My comments will remain posted. Content is not being removed - just a list (whereby I can click individual ones to go to the page on the site. I don't ever use that facility.) Once the current list is dumped, a new one will automatically start for my comments thereafter.

Comment: On the top black bar here, a symbol shows INBOX (ALL) when clicked, and I mark as 'Read' all those I read. Having done that, how do I delete all those listed as read?

Comment: Try clicking on Inbox (All) and select Inbox (unread) instead. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Stevecanhelp Yes! That worked! I was confounded because I individually mark each one as read once I've read them, so thought 'Select unread' would be inapplicable, because I'd read them. Female logic is a strange thing, uh? Thank you so much, Steve.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)